# Excel - looking for coincidence of two different values in two different columns and extract another column

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am trying to extract the value like what we can do with vlookup, but in this case it has to coincide with the value on two different columns.

I want to extract the values which match with the two columns in yellow.

Sheet1 (where I am looking for coincidence of two values)
[image: Sheet1 (where I am looking for coincidence of two values)]

For that I am using the formula IF(COUNTIFS(....)=1;"value that I am looking for"; no match)

But I don´t know what to put on "value that I am looking for", because if I add directly the cell from the row, it delivers directly a wrong value.

Sheet2 (where I want to add these two values, and formula that I am testing)

[image: Sheet2 (where I want to add these two values, and formula that I am testing)]

Answer (score 0):

If you have O365, you can use a combination of `INDEX` and `FILTER` function to do this

```
=INDEX(FILTER('Sheet 1'!$A$2:$E$10,('Sheet 1'!$A$2:$A$10='Sheet 2'!$B192)*('Sheet 1'!$E$2:$E$10='Sheet 2'!$C192),""),1,2)
```

You need to update the `'Sheet 1'!$A$2:$E$10` range according to your data.

Also note that this will return the 1st match of both `Partner object` and `Value in Obj. Crcy` row, even if there are multiple matches

---

## Edit:

As suggested by [@P.b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12634230) in the comments below, you can also use:

```
=@FILTER('Sheet 1'!$B$2:$B$10,('Sheet 1'!$A$2:$A$10='Sheet 2'!$B192)*('Sheet 1'!$E$2:$E$10='Sheet 2'!$C192),"")
```

Comment: Wouldn't `=@FILTER('Sheet 1'!$B$2:$B$10,('Sheet 1'!$A$2:$A$10='Sheet 2'!$B192)*('Sheet 1'!$E$2:$E$10='Sheet 2'!$C192),"")` do the same? Since `@` returns the first instance and filter range can be brought down to the desired column there would not be the need to index it.

Comment: Wow, I wasn't aware of the `@` keyword can be used this way in Excel formula's. I assumed they are limited to Tables. That's really awesome. @P.b Do you have any link to the official documentation mentioning the use of `@` in formulas?

Comment: Basically it means "in this row". Found this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34